# Online Compiler to check execution time

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, editor

I want to know any available Code compiler (C++ specifically) which gives the total execution time of submitted code.

To my knowledge, **Ideone** being good online compiler **doesn't** provide this feature. 
It'd very great if there exists a service to check the execution time (Total Running time) for a code.

Comment: You could just add a couple of calls to `gettimeofday()` at the start and end of `main()` and generate the elapsed time yourself ?

Comment: Yeah! That's possible on the system. But I wanted to know if there any service available along with the compiler.
@ShafikYaghmour: Upto 2 decimal places.

Comment: What's the point? You have absolutely no idea of the spec of the server, what else it is doing at the time, what kind of sandbox your code runs in, ...

Comment: Basic idea behind this is to test the execution time of the code before submitting to the online judges for programming contests.

Comment: Why can't you do that locally? liveworkspace did this, by the way, but that has been under "temporary maintenance" for months. Shame, it was my favourite for posting examples.

Comment: If it is just for a rough heuristic than [rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode) provides this information I don't think other do but you could use `time` command in front of command on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

Comment: @BoBTFish: I mentioned already , locally it could be calculated but i was in a search for an online solution.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Thanks man ! rextester does it :)

Comment: You may also want to check out [Online C++ compiler and evaluator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) which pretty much covers all the online compilers out there that I know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[rextester](http://rextester.com/) provides this information, for example I just ran their default C++ program I see the following output above the results:

> Compilation time: 0.83 sec, absolute running time: 0.15 sec, cpu time: 0 sec, memory peak: 3 Mb, absolute service time: 0.99 sec (cached)

those are pretty rough numbers and your are limited to `5` seconds of cpu time. The other simple option is to use `time` when you execute on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). For example I modified the default command as follows:

```
set -x ; g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && time ./a.out
                                                                     ^^^^
```

this will provide you with output like this:

```
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
```